# Can you clarify the structure "impress somebody with/by something"?

Tags: expressions, syntactic-analysis, expression-choice, by-with

I found this structure in ldoceonline.com but I am a bit confused about it.

Ok,

> ***to impress somebody with/by something***: to make someone feel admiration
>   and respect about something ([Source](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/impress))

And the [Source](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/impress) has these examples:

**Example 1**: *We were very impressed by the standard of work.*

I think the above sentence can be rewritten as

*The standard of work impresses us*.

So, I think that the "*by*" in this case is the preposition of passive form

Ok, some of you may say that it can be expressed as:

"*The company impresses us by the standard of work.*" and when changing to passive form, we can omit "*by the company*".

However, if that is the case, then the sentence should be written as "*The company impresses us by its standard of work.*" thus can be changed as "*We were impressed (by the company) by its standard of work.*" and "*by the company*" can be omitted in this case.

**Example 2**: *One candidate in particular impressed us with her knowledge.*

I think the above sentence can be rewritten as

*One candidate in particular impressed us by her knowledge.*

So, I think that the "*by*" in this case is not the preposition of passive form, but just a normal preposition. I think "*by*" in this case is an alternative of "*with*".

Therefore, can I change the second example to the following?

*We were impressed by one candidate (in particular) by her knowledge.*

So, in this case, the first "*by*" is the preposition of passive form while the second "*by*" is a normal preposition and an alternative of "*with*"

Since this is confusing me, so I want to ask you:

Can you clarify the structure "**impress somebody with/by something**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company impressed us by the standard of work. -> We were impressed by the company's standard of work.

One candidate in particular impressed us with her knowledge. -> We were impressed by a particular candidate's knowledge.

In other words, you get to recombine words in creative ways.